# Variable content doesn't show up when I use it in HTML (from Python, Flask)

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a survey for a school project with Python, and I've been trying to generate some questions about the well-known Trolley Problem, but it doesn't work.

The variables don't show up, even though I'm using a "for" function. The selection length does work; I'm not getting the error message. The randomly chosen variables just don't show up.
The `<p>` tags do show up and are there a random (1-4) amount of times every time I refresh.

!! kwant is short for quantity, sel is short for selection, mens translated is human !!

Code: (Python with Flask)

```
    @app.route('/start')
def start():
    mensen = ["Young man", "Old man", "Clinically depressed young man", "Clinically depressed old man", "Young woman", "Old woman", "Clinically depressed young woman", "Clinically depressed old woman"]
    kwant1 = randint(1,4)
    kwant2 = randint(1,4)
    sel1 = random.choices(mensen, k=kwant1)
    sel2 = random.choices(mensen, k=kwant2)
    return render_template('quiz.html', sel1=sel1, sel2=sel2)
```

HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Trolley Problem Quiz</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="main">
    <h2>Question</h2>
    <div style="width: 40%; float:left; margin:5%">
        <h3>Choice 1</h3>
        <p>If the train follows its natural course, it'll run over</p>
        <br>
        {% if sel1|length > 0 %}
            {% for mens in sel1 %}
                <p>{{ mens.content }}</p>

            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <p>Er was een error toen dit geladen werd. <a href="/">Klik hier om het opnieuw te proberen.</a></p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div style="width: 40%; float:left; margin:5%">
        <h3>Choice 2</h3>
        <p>If the train turns, it'll run over</p>
        <br>
        {% if sel2|length > 0 %}
            {% for mens2 in sel2 %}
                <p>{{ mens2.content }}</p>

            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>error message</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure if the code is wrong (I'm a pretty new programmer) so I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I was able to run a flask server, navigate to `/start` and render the quiz template - so your code *runs*. Beyond that, I can't assist further unless you are more specific with *what* the actual issue is. Saying that the *"code is wrong"* is not descriptive enough. You need to [edit] your question with some details about what you expect to happen and what is going wrong. On another note, the prevalent use of non-English throughout the code will be a barrier in giving quality answers; please try to translate it (to English).

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post! I translated all the dutch parts to english, and I tried to explain it better. Thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: try using {{ mens }} instead of {{ mens.content }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lists `sel1` and `sel2` contain strings. Yet, in your HTML template, when you refer to those lists, you try to access a non-existent `content` attribute. Strings in Python have no such attribute.

Hence, where you have:

```
<p>{{ mens.content }}</p>
```

and

```
<p>{{ mens2.content }}</p>
```

it should instead be:

```
<p>{{ mens }}</p>
```

and

```
<p>{{ mens2 }}</p>
```